# Vaadin align buttons

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin7

I have 4 buttons in a Gridlayout.

[image]

I have used

```
btnDetails.setSizeUndefined();
buttonsGrid.setComponentAlignment(btnDetails, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);
```

But as you can see the buttons are not with same width because of the **setSizeUndefined();**

When I specify the width and the height of the buttons I get this result

[image]

You can see that in this way the buttons are not aligned.
I have included

```
 buttonsGrid.setComponentAlignment(btnDetails, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);
```

but it seems this is not working without **setSizeUndefined();**

I need the buttons to be aligned as in the first picture but with same width.

Thanks,
Kiril

Comment: I think you need to align the button icons and the button caption with scss to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `text-align: left` in your theme? Something like this (for Vaadin 8 replace `FontAwesome` with `VaadinIcons`):

**Java:**

```
public class GridLayoutWithLeftAlignedButtons extends GridLayout {
    public GridLayoutWithLeftAlignedButtons() {
        super(1, 4);
        addButton("Details", FontAwesome.SEARCH);
        addButton("Copy (Inhalt)", FontAwesome.FILE_TEXT);
        addButton("Copy (Zeile)", FontAwesome.COPY);
        addButton("Copy (ID)", FontAwesome.SERVER);
    }

    private void addButton(String caption, FontAwesome icon) {
        Button newButton = new Button(caption, icon);
        newButton.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_BORDERLESS);
        newButton.addStyleName("black-background-white-text");
        newButton.setWidth("300px");
        addComponent(newButton);
    }
}
```

**Theme:**

```
.v-button.black-background-white-text{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: vaadin-button-caption-alignment]

Comment: Mulțumesc Morfic

Comment: @KireProgramista :-) you're definitely most welcome. Minor note, 'tho: I guess at this point `setComponentAlignment(newButton, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);` is kind of useless, so it can be removed. I had copy-pasted it from your sample and I just noticed you can save 1 more line of code...